# Adding a time stamp on post view

Tags: posts, ajax, json

Hi there we are using this ajax function to update the views of our custom "posts"

```
    if( !empty( $_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] == 'update_view_count' && !empty($_REQUEST['attach_id']) ) {
    $count = get_post_meta($_REQUEST['attach_id'], 'view_count', true);
    if( !is_numeric($count) ) $count = 0;
    if( update_post_meta($_REQUEST['attach_id'], 'view_count', $count + 1) === FALSE ) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Failed to update view_count for ' . $_REQUEST['attach_id']));
    }
    else {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Updated ' . $_REQUEST['attach_id'] . ' view_count to ' . ($count + 1)));
    }
    die();
    }
```

We want to add time stamp on it. Any ideas how to do that? I also wanted to add that we don't need to keep track indefinitely, we need it to be tracked for 5 days, then reset.

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there, I'd say. I am sure there are many ways to do this. If it were me, I'd build a 'nested' array for this. Something like...

```
array(
    'timestamp-1' = array(
        'message' => 'Updated post1',
        'message' => 'Updated post1'
    ),
    'timestamp-2' = array(
        'message' => 'Updated post3',
        'message' => 'Updated post4',
        'message' => 'Updated post5'
    )
)
```

... where 'timestamp-N' is midnight or midday or some arbitrary value for a particular day. You can run [`wp-cron`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) daily to check the array and clean it up. I suggest doing it this way because using a minute-and-second timestamp means having to check and manipulate that array pretty much every page load.